# Get Return Value from pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to create a PYQT UI where a user can enter 2 values so that those values can be used in a calculation in a different file or method. How can I get a return of those values to be used? Here is my code (I tried using other examples online):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class GetLength(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent= None):
        super(GetLength, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)

         self.LenLabel = QLabel('Please enter Length:')
         self.grid.addWidget(self.LenLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1)
         self.WidLabel = QLabel('Please enter Width:')
         self.grid.addWidget(self.WidLabel, 2, 0, 1, 1)

         self.Length = QLineEdit(self)
         self.grid.addWidget(self.Length, 1, 1, 1, 1)
         self.Width = QLineEdit(self)
         self.grid.addWidget(self.Width, 2, 1, 1, 1)

         self.submit = QPushButton('Submit', clicked=self.EnterButton)
         self.grid.addWidget(self.submit, 4, 1, 1, 1)

     def EnterButton(self):
         a = self.Length.text()
         b = self.Width.text()
         return self.a, self.b
```

From main file:

```
from GetLength import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
edit_params__QD = GetLength()
edit_params__QD.exec_()
if edit_params__QD.result() == 0:
    value1, value2 = edit_params__QD.EnterButton()
    print('Success!', value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class GetLength(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent= None):
        super(GetLength, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)

        self.LenLabel = QLabel('Please enter Length:')
        self.grid.addWidget(self.LenLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.WidLabel = QLabel('Please enter Width:')
        self.grid.addWidget(self.WidLabel, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Length = QLineEdit(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Length, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Width = QLineEdit(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Width, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.submit = QPushButton('Submit', clicked=self.EnterButton)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.submit, 4, 1, 1, 1)

    def EnterButton(self):
        a = self.Length.text()
        b = self.Width.text()

        self.close()                                                 # +++
#        return self.a, self.b
        return a, b                                                  # +++

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
edit_params__QD = GetLength()
edit_params__QD.exec_()

if edit_params__QD.result() == 0:
    value1, value2 = edit_params__QD.EnterButton()
    print('Success!', value1, value2)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! I guess I haven't grasp the self variable yet. When should I use self?

Comment: @J.D.  You must use `self` when you need access to a variable in another class method. For example, you have an object `self.Length` created in the class `GetLength` in the method `def __init __ ()` and you need to use it in another method `def EnterButton (self)`. `self` means that the object is available in any method of the class.
When you do `return self.a, self.b` you get an error because there are no such objects, they were not created. But you created the object `a = self.Length.text ()` and `b`, you need their return `return a, b`.

Comment: Gotcha, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the dialog window when `Submit` button is pressed so put `accept` into `clicked` handler:

```
    self.submit = QPushButton('Submit', clicked=self.accept)
```

Then fix `EnterButton` to return local variables:

```
def EnterButton(self):
    a = self.Length.text()
    b = self.Width.text()        
    return a, b
```

Then on caller site check whether dialog was closed as accepted or not, by checking `result() == 1`:

```
if edit_params__QD.result() == 1:
```